# Is there a way to put text in an invisible text box with html5 canvas' fillText method?

Tags: javascript, html, text

I'm making an HTML5 game, and I need a way to textually inform the player about things. I'd like to put the text in this box, using the fillText method:

[image]

Now, I only know how to render the text in one line, but that obviously wouldn't suffice, because there need to be linebreaks for the text to fit. Is there a way to do this quickly, or will I have to code it myself?

This is how a message looks ingame:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the [spec](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#drawing-text-to-the-canvas), you'll have to do it yourself if you want to use only canvas.

To do so, you'll need to use `measureText` in order to get the size of your text and to break it manually. But that seems quite bothersome.

Another solution that I find more elegant is to use an overlay of HTML. The HTML to use for that could look like that:

```
<div id="outer" syle="position:relative">
   <canvas id='myCanvas'/>
   <div id="textualDiv" syle="position:absolute"></div>
</div>
```

You'd then position `textualDiv` according to your need and you'll just fill it when you'll need it. After that you'll just hide it. And show it again  when the need arise.

Comment: I agree with @Py solution. I recommend you use the DIV overlay approach if your text will be very dynamic in contents and size. `fillText()` would be appropriate if all the messages to be drawn are known beforehand.